# How to capture milliseconds in IIS 10 log files?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-10

I have enabled IIS logging to capture a bunch of fields in Windows server 2016 with IIS 10. Here is the screen shot of the fields I have selected.

[image]

I could see that log files are getting generated and log entries are written for all the http traffic. The Time field is only displaying hour, minute and seconds in Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), at which the request occurred.

Here is an example of the log entry where Time filed is just displaying 15:07:37 (HH:mm:ss).

> 2017-11-30 15:07:37 15.79.72.01 POST /IntegrationService/api/products/
>   - 80 ADX/userxyz 132.40.11.16 - - 200 0 0 62

How can I capture milliseconds part of the time field? 
I looked at the documentation from Microsoft but I don't see any details around it.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/provisioning-and-managing-iis/configure-logging-in-iis

**UPDATE:**
I thought may be Stackoverflow is not the right place for this question, so I have posted this question in ServerFalut site. Here is the link.

https://serverfault.com/questions/886021/how-to-capture-milliseconds-in-iis-10-log-files

Comment: you got your answer in server fault. I am just mentioning the same thing here for sake of others who get to this question. W3C extended spec that IIS logging follows by default does not mention time in milliseconds, so,it is not implemented. You will need to look at an alternative.